# Role based menu angularJs using JSON

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I created a menu from JSON using AngularJS. I want to show or hide it on the bases of roles assigned to users. I have two roles, **Admin** and **HeadQuarter**. I want to show Manage Inventory and Sale Inventory menu to **HeadQuarter** role only and only show Sale Inventory to **Admin** role

Here is my code:

```
$scope.Menu = [
    {
        Name: 'Manage Inventory',
        SubMenu: [{
            Name: 'Manage Products',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchProduct', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Manage SubCategories',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchSubCategory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Manage Categories',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchCategory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Manage Departments',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchDepartment', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'View/Print Inventory',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchInventory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Stock Taking',
            Link: { Action: 'StockTaking', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }]
},
{
        Name: 'Sales',
        SubMenu: [{
            Name: 'Sale Products',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchProduct', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Manage SubCategories',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchSubCategory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Sale Categories',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchCategory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Sale Departments',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchDepartment', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'View/Print Inventory',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchInventory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Stock Taking',
            Link: { Action: 'StockTaking', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }]
}
```

];

Here I am getting roles:

```
var _hrole = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("HeadQuarter")));
    var _wrole = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin")));
```

`_hrole` and `_wrole` are booleans, that are either true or false, depending on the role.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="r in Menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{r.Name}}</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-include="'_nestedMenuTemplate'" ng-init="Menu = r.SubMenu"></ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `_hrole` and `_wrole` would not be `boolean` - they are `string`. If you want a `boolean` then use `var _hrole = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("HeadQuarter")))`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I am getting true or false now but still don't know how to show hide it

Comment: After fixing the indentation of your code, it seems like you are missing a closing `}` brace in `$scope.Menu`.

Comment: You provided code with the menu data and I see that you have variables to determine the role of the person. I do not see any code with an attempt to actually show or hide the menu. What have you tried and what results have you gotten?

Comment: Basically i don't know to show hide it that's why i posted a question here to help me achieve my goal. If you can please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `_hrole` value as a way to toggle the display style, like the following:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("HeadQuarter")) ? "display:block" : "display:none")">
```

---

Another option would be to add a simple jQuery call that toggles the nav bar's visibility based on the value of `_hrole`.

The easiest way would be to add an id to your nav bar `ul` item:

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
```

Your jQuery code would then look something like the following:

```
if(_hrole) {
    $('#menu').show();
}
else {
    $('#menu').hide();
}
```

Comment: only html file why you can use @Html.Raw ?

Comment: I have other menu item as well show them to admin role

Comment: @ShamshadJamal Ok, then it makes sense to have a second variable, although it is not really related to this question. I removed that part from my answer.

Comment: @ShamshadJamal What does the data you added have anything to do with the question. The actual data inside the menu is irrelevant, no?

Comment: @thanhdung0312 Since the OP used it, I assumed they are using Razor with ASP.NET MVC, and not just plain HTML.

Comment: I just want to make it simple to understand it more easily rather than explain it in plan English as my English is not good enough. I think its better to show all code i wrote to the community it will also help me to correct and improve my coding skills

Comment: I am using angularjs

Comment: @ShamshadJamal You should only include the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem. Extra code actually detracts from your question and makes it harder to narrow down the problem and provide an answer.

Comment: @TotZam : context page is file .html or .cshtml

Comment: @TotZam next time i will try my best to minimize my code thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Its a .cshtml page but i am binding ul li using JSON with angularJs

Comment: @ShamshadJamal You just changed your entire question with an edit, so this solution will not work. The basic idea of using `_hrole` and `_whole` as variables to toggle the element's visibility does still stand though, so you can try using this idea as start from your solution.

Comment: @TotZam that's also not the solution for this question thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this way:

Step 1: you have to config which menu need to show. If the menu has that role, UI will show it, anything else hidden it. You add RoleShowMenu field to $scope.Menu. this field contain role will show.

```
$scope.Menu = [
    {
        Name: 'Manage Inventory',
        RoleShowMenu : ['HeadQuarter']
        SubMenu: [{
            Name: 'Manage Products',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchProduct', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Manage SubCategories',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchSubCategory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Manage Categories',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchCategory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Manage Departments',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchDepartment', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'View/Print Inventory',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchInventory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Stock Taking',
            Link: { Action: 'StockTaking', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }]
},
{
        Name: 'Sales',
        RoleShowMenu : ['Admin', 'HeadQuarter']
        SubMenu: [{
            Name: 'Sale Products',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchProduct', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Manage SubCategories',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchSubCategory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Sale Categories',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchCategory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Sale Departments',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchDepartment', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'View/Print Inventory',
            Link: { Action: 'SearchInventory', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }, {
            Name: 'Stock Taking',
            Link: { Action: 'StockTaking', Controller: 'Inventory' }
        }]
}
];
```

Step 2: by the way you have to get role of user login after set to $rootScope . Use $rootScope to cache data.
Example when login by XXX user , you will get XXX' role user. To get role you can call Rest API or any way. Assume that XXX user has 'HeadQuarter' role.

```
$rootScope.rolesUserLogin = 'HeadQuarter';
```

Step 3: create function to check show/hiden menu by role:

```
$rootScope.hasRole = function (roleShowMenu) {
    for (var i=0; i< roleShowMenu.length; i++) {
        if (roleShowMenu[i] === $rootScope.rolesUserLogin ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Step 4 : apply for HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="r in Menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ng-if="hasRole(r.RoleShowMenu)">{{r.Name}}</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-include="'_nestedMenuTemplate'" ng-init="Menu = r.SubMenu" ng-if="hasRole(r.RoleShowMenu)"></ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have implemented the code but it always gives me undefined return false

Comment: On html page you what is the value of RoleShowMenu param? You can share for me about that

Comment: its either HeadQuarter or Admin depending upon role

Comment: When you run app , you can debug to hasRole in angularjs and check result method